# Use Triangle Inequalities to Prove an Inequality

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

Use the triangle inequalities to prove that:

$$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}\le\frac{|a|}{1+|a|} + \frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I've made it this far, but it doesn't seem to be helping much; what I end up with at the end isn't very useful:

[image]

Clearly I'm taking a wrong turn somewhere, but I'm not sure what else to try.  Any advice?

Comment: You aren't considering that $|a|+|b| \ge |a|$.  So you are closer than you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}=1-\frac{1}{1+|a+b|}\leq1-\frac{1}{1+|a|+|b|}=$$
$$=\frac{|a|}{1+|a|+|b|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|a|+|b|}\leq\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}.$$

Comment: Man, I should have known to try that considering the form it was written in.  Thanks a bundle.